# How to add an error to request context rather than throw exception in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I set an error in **Request Context** rather than throw an **Exception**?

Like:

```
void valid(Object o){        
    if(o == null){
        //add an error to Request context
        //I want to avoid the throw new ....
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain **why** you want to avoid to throw an exception? That's actually a pretty nice solution in my eyes. Easy to catch and great for testing.

Comment: Wow, I was searching and reading about.. and a lot of text are telling to avoid exceptions and use error messages...

Comment: Well, I use them. No expert though, don't use it as advice if you think other ways work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe exception is not a functionality to be avoided.
It was created for a purpose, and should be used in this way.

The problem is when devs use them to help on the application's flow, because exception is an expensive solution for that, and there are other ways for doing so.

There is nothing wrong in throwing a BadRequestException for example when there is some user input failure. Some frameworks are already expecting specific exceptions, and most of them is already prepared for treatment for customized exceptions.